# Exception while running AWS dynamoDb in Local Machine

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have downloaded AWS dynamodb zip file and extracted to D:/dynamoDB folder
When tried to run via command prompt using

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

Exception as below occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: completionKey
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.initIDs(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(Unknown Source)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.DateCache.<init>(DateCache.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.<clinit>(StdErrLog.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initStandardLogging(Log.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:425)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO.<clinit>(IO.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log$1.run(Log.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.<clinit>(AbstractL
ifeCycle.java:33)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.createServe
r(ServerRunner.java:123)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.createServe
rFromCommandLineArgs(ServerRunner.java:119)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.main(Server
Runner.java:70)
```

I am having Java7 sdk in my windows 32 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NoSuchFieldError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html) exceptions are thrown "if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field".  In this case, it's likely the jar was compiled against one version of java (or other dependency) and you're using a different version that is not compatible.

I'd suggest updating to Java8 since [support for Java7 ended as of April 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).  Also, check your version of jetty (since the last call outside the JVM was caused by `org.eclipse.jetty.util.DateCache.<init>(DateCache.java:88)`) to make sure it's compatible.

Comment: problem was with java version.